# Ruby on Rails Routing with Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to create a comment model for my posts and the question is how am I able to create comments but not have the routes nested inside of the posts...

That is, there is no route to `posts/comment/:comment_id` and instead just have the user enter a comment and let the user stay on the page without having to transfer the user. I want the user to have no interaction with a different route and just have them say where they are.

Comment: What is your data model?  Does a comment belong to a post?  If so, how do you attach a comment and a post?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but if you don't want the user to be taken to a new page after creating a comment just remove the "render" method in the action for the comment controller.